# PCF page issue with capitalization

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I am trying to make a field on a PCF page capitalized. It's a field that is stored in the entity. I am trying to do:

```
contact.FirstName.toUpperCase()
```

But since it's an editable field I can't use toUpperCase. Is there a way to format a text input field on the PCF page to display in all capitals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `outputConversion` attribute, e.g.:

```
<TextInput
    editable="true"
    id="FirstName"
    label="First Name"
    outputConversion="VALUE.toUpperCase()"
    value="Person.FirstName"/>
```

P.S. There is also an `inputConversion` attribute which can be used if you want to modify data before storing it.